# Data Structure for application routes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, web-applications, routes

Web frameworks route incoming requests to endpoints by matching the request path against a series of regular expressions. So what would be a good/best data structure to use for storing request path(with wildcards).

And if any such package(in any language)?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions support much more than wildcards. A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) can usually be used to match prefixes, as long as they are unique, but for matching the logical OR of a list of alternatives, look into something like the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

However, these algorithms/data structures only take into account the static part of the lookup, i.e. matching predictable strings. For wildcard matching, if you allow arbitrary backtracking you can get pathological performance, which means that using a full regular expression system in a path router is probably not a good idea as it can lead to denial of service.

Check out [this write up](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) on how Go converts regular expressions (though of a limited form) into a [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) using [Thmopson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction).